# Как сохранить картинку Jpeg в поле Image Ms Sql ?

Tags: jpeg, sql-server, visual-studio

Кто работал в Visual Studio с Ms Sql, дайте код записи картинки Jpeg BMP в поле типа Image.

Answer (score 1):

При условии, что вы загрузили изображение в массив байтов `image` (`byte[] image`) на C#

```
// Инициализировать подключение к SQL Server
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("...");

// Прописать запрос на вставку
string q = "insert into Images (Image) values(@Image)";

// Создать команду на вставку
SqlCommand с = new SqlCommand(q, connection);

// Передать параметры
c.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Image", (object)image));

// Открыть соединение и выполнить запрос
connection.Open();
c.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```